# I want to get rid of cacheKey error in .rs.WorkingDataEnv

Tags: r, rstudio

```
Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
```

I used the `rm()` function in R to delete a couple of data frames. They were successfully deleted. However, this prompt kept popping up anytime I ran a new code.

Comment: This is possibly related to this https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13188

Answer (score 31):

I faced the same error today. For me, it was fixed after restarting Rstudio. You could simply restart by clicking on `Session -> Restart R` in the top bar. After that, I was able to run my code again without any error.

Answer (score 9):

This error message is now fixed in RStudio versions 2023.06.1-524 and later. https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13188 refers.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a problem with the IDE (R-Studio). I was able to solve the problem after updating R-Studio to the latest build: 2023.06 Mountain Hydrangea, in the link below:

[2023.06 Mountain Hydrangea](https://dailies.rstudio.com/rstudio/mountain-hydrangea/)

Comment: Still getting the same bug with this version - annoying hopefully it gets fixed soon

Comment: The fix starts with build 2023.06.1+437, so you shouldn't have problem beyond that version number.

Answer (score 2):

Closing and reopening the script worked for me.