# Random error when using read.table() function in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, read.table

```
#Set important packages
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

#Set working directory
setwd("C:/Users/data") 

#Read table
wd <- read.table("data.txt",header=T, dec=".", fill=FALSE)
str(wd)
```

I am rather new in the community, I am basically running chunks of the code including some ggplot. But when I realize I need to modify a bit more the data set and go back to the loading of the file this error comes up.

Is normally fixed when I close the program and open it again, but not convenient for the long run. Has anyone experience this and how did you solve it?

Thank you in advance!!
Here is the error:

```
Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
```

Is normally fixed when I close the program and open it again, but not convenient for the long run. Has anyone experience this and how did you solve it?

Comment: Apparently this is a known bug that was fixed in newer releases, see https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13188.

Comment: There is also a previous question here on Stack Overflow, which mentions that you can fix the error with an update: [I want to get rid of cacheKey error in .rs.WorkingDataEnv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76558629/i-want-to-get-rid-of-cachekey-error-in-rs-workingdataenv)